# El implementation is not found for hibernate-validator in osgi-container

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi, hibernate-validator, apache-servicemix

I try to run Hibernate validator in osgi container.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.Final_1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>


public class HibernateValidationProviderResolver implements ValidationProviderResolver {
    @Override
    public List<ValidationProvider<?>> getValidationProviders() {
        List<ValidationProvider<?>> list = new ArrayList<>(1);
        list.add(new HibernateValidator());
        return list;
    }
}


Configuration<?> configuration = Validation.byDefaultProvider().providerResolver(
    new HibernateValidationProviderResolver()
).configure();

ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = configuration.buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Group>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(group);


public class Group {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2)
    private String title;
}
```

Try to run, equinox console is okay:

```
10      RESOLVED    org.glassfish.web.javax.el_2.2.4
39      RESOLVED    org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hibernate-validator_5.0.2.Final_1
47      RESOLVED    javax.validation.api_1.1.0.Final
49      RESOLVED    javax.el-api_2.2.4
```

If I pass Group class instance with `title = null`, then validation is okay and constraintViolations contains one violation "not null".
If I pass Group class instance with `title = "A"` (one character against minimal length = 2), then it throws an exception

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
```

It 100% caused by osgi, but how I should setup hibernate-validator in osgi? All articles what I can found describes creating of `HibernateValidationProviderResolver` and that's all.

**UPDATE 1**

```
Maven: javax.el:javax.el-api:2.2.4

Export-Package: javax.el;version="2.2.4"
Import-Package: javax.el;version="2.2.4"

Maven: org.glassfish.web:javax.el:2.2.4 MANIFEST.MF

Export-Package: com.sun.el;uses:="javax.el";version="2.2.4"
Private-Package: com.sun.el.lang;version="2.2.4",com.sun.el.parser;version="2.2.4",com.sun.el.util;version="2.2.4"
Import-Package: com.sun.el;version="2.2.4",javax.el;version="2.2"

Maven: org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hibernate-validator:5.0.2.Final_1

Implementation-Version: 5.0.2.Final
Import-Package: javax.el,javax.persistence;resolution:=optional, ...

Export-Package: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpola
tion.el;uses:="javax.el,javax.validation,org.hibernate.validator.intern
al.engine.messageinterpolation";version="5.0.2.Final",org.hibernate.val
idator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation;uses:="javax.validation.met
adata,org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.el,j
avax.el,javax.validation,org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging"
;version="5.0.2.Final", ...
```

Any version for import in hibernate bundle, 2.2.4 in export of el-api and el-impl and el-impl imports el-api as 2.2, not a 2.2.4. All bundles are resolved.

**Update 2**

**Decision 1**

my implementation of @hwellmann's idea. @hwellmann, is it correct?

```
public void createGroup(Group group) {
    ClassLoader prevClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    try {
        ClassLoader[] classLoaders = new ClassLoader[] {
            prevClassLoader,
            ExpressionFactoryImpl.class.getClassLoader()
        };

        // build composite classloader

        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(compositeClassLoader);

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Group>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(group);

    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(prevClassLoader);
    }
}
```

It works but looks strange. And change TCCL on each validation processing looks as some overhead.

**Decision 2**

The error has gone when I add my own message attribute to each validation annotation, for example for Group:

```
public class Group {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, message="field.too_short")
    private String title;
}
```

It seems in this case hibernate interpolator is not started so `ExpressionFactoryImpl` is not retrieved from TCCL (previously we read min=2 value, now we don't). If it is okay for us, this decision is simplest.
I will investigate this area futhermore and share my observations there.

Comment: how's the import/export packages for the hibernate validation bundle? Might very well be that the validation bundle doesn't import the right package, or the el-bundle doesn't export those as expected.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck, thank you for your attention! I have updated the post. Now I'll try to change versions (el-api and el-impl) and implementations of el-api. May be it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full stack trace might give some more insight than just the exception messages.

My guess is that you're seeing the results of a failed service lookup via `META-INF/service/javax.el.ExpressionFactory`. The bundle that's doing the lookup apparently can't see `com.sun.el`.

Importing this package into your application bundle and setting the thread context classloader to your bundle classloader might help.

Comment: yep, you are right, changing of TCCL fix the issue. Please, look at my implementation in Update 2, it is my first time when I change TCCL in osgi, is it correct implementation? Should I do it on each validation (on the controller validation stage)? And of course, I think, I can accept your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is a related issue in JBoss Fuse:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1479723

They recommend a downgrade to `4.3.1.Final`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Pawel, it looks interesting. I have not discovered this link by search. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Hibernate 5.2.5 and Jetty 9.x. Basically, it looked like Hibernate didn't check if there was already an EL implementation on the classpath and tried to use javax.el-api instead of Jetty 9's apache-el. An upgrade to Hibernate 5.2.10 solved the issue for me. No conflicting el-api on the classpath any more.

Answer (score 0):

## Background

I use hibernate validator version 5.4.3.Final.

Starting from [5.3.1.Final](https://in.relation.to/2016/11/10/hibernate-validator-532-final-out/), it mentions that ExpressionFactoryImpl is a hard requirement.

there is OSGi issue in 5.3.1.Final,issue is **ClassLoader issues in modularized environments**. It has been fixed in 5.3.3.Final. Ticket number is[HV-1155](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1155)

## Fix

Based on the above information,
there is no need to use **Update 2 -> Decision 1**.
I found out that you could simply change the code posted by OP from

```
Configuration<?> configuration = Validation.byDefaultProvider().providerResolver(
    new HibernateValidationProviderResolver()
).configure();
```

to

```
Configuration<?> configuration = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).providerResolver(
    new HibernateValidationProviderResolver()
).externalClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).configure();
```

[11.15. Customizing class-loading](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-customizing-class-loading) mentions this trick.

In addition, if you are using hibernate validator version 6.0.0.CR3 above, you don't need to apply the trick above.[HV-1426](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1426) covers it.